# Map arrays with duplicate indexes?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, slice

Assume three arrays in numpy:

```
a = np.zeros(5)
b = np.array([3,3,3,0,0])
c = np.array([1,5,10,50,100])
```

b can now be used as an index for a and c. For example:

```
   In [142]: c[b]
   Out[142]: array([50, 50, 50,  1,  1])
```

Is there any way to add up the values connected to the duplicate indexes with this kind of slicing? With

```
a[b] = c
```

Only the last values are stored:

```
 array([ 100.,    0.,    0.,   10.,    0.])
```

I would like something like this:

```
a[b] += c
```

which would give

```
 array([ 150.,    0.,    0.,   16.,    0.])
```

I'm mapping very large vectors onto 2D matrices and would really like to avoid loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def sum_unique(label, weight):
    order = np.lexsort(label.T)
    label = label[order]
    weight = weight[order]
    unique = np.ones(len(label), 'bool')
    unique[:-1] = (label[1:] != label[:-1]).any(-1)
    totals = weight.cumsum()
    totals = totals[unique]
    totals[1:] = totals[1:] - totals[:-1]
    return label[unique], totals
```

And use it like this:

```
In [110]: coord = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 2))

In [111]: coord
Out[111]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [112]: weights = np.ones(10)

In [113]: uniq_coord, sums = sum_unique(coord, weights)

In [114]: uniq_coord
Out[114]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [115]: sums
Out[115]: array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  3.])

In [116]: a = np.zeros((3,3))

In [117]: x, y = uniq_coord.T

In [118]: a[x, y] = sums

In [119]: a
Out[119]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.]])
```

I just thought of this, it might be easier:

```
In [120]: flat_coord = np.ravel_multi_index(coord.T, (3,3))

In [121]: sums = np.bincount(flat_coord, weights)

In [122]: a = np.zeros((3,3))

In [123]: a.flat[:len(sums)] = sums

In [124]: a
Out[124]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+=` operator for NumPy arrays simply doesn't work the way you are hoping, and I'm not aware of a away of making it work that way.  As a work-around I suggest using `numpy.bincount()`:

```
>>> numpy.bincount(b, c)
array([ 150.,    0.,    0.,   16.])
```

Just append zeros as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had now idea that bincount existed- it will be been very useful for other implementations. Would it be possible to use this approach for 2D arrays as well? My real world problem consists of three 10^7 element vectors (x-pos, y-pos, value) that I'm mapping to a 2D array.

Comment: @brorfred: You can reinterpret your array as a 1D array without copying using its `reshape()` method and then apply `bincount()`.